# Handling dots and dashes as delimiters for DNS Host Names using a RegEx pattern

Tags: c#, regex, dns, hostname

I’m troubleshooting an old .NET 3.0 app that reads free form text files, Email logs, and parses text using C# to retrieve an IP Address and or a DNS Host Name. The problem is complicated by constraints imposed by our other internal apps which require specific formatting of a Host Name when stored in a DB. Currently, in this old app, Host Names are formatted with dot delimiters just like IP Addresses. This needs to be updated to allow dashes as a delimiter on Host Names while keeping the domain component of a Host Name delimited with dots.  Two that end, two copies of a Host Name will be stored, the original as retuned in a DNS query, and a modified version compliant with existing systems.

More specifically, the problem I’ve run into is when a DNS Host Name has an IP Address as part of the Host Name, such as "abc121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com", such strings need to be formatted like this, "abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com".

Notice the delimiters used on the Host Name are different than those on the domain component. I’d like to do this with RegEx, and have been using a starter pattern I found on this website, but my skills are inadequate for tweaking these any further, assuming that’s even possible.

What I need is to be able to get the IP Address from a Host Name when that’s the only place an IP appears, and I need to force the use of dashes as delimiters on the Host Name component of a fully qualified DNS Host Name.

The 1st example below pulls an IP Address out of a Host Name just fine, but only when the delimiters used in the IP parts are dots. I'm looking for a RegEx that pulls the IP out regardless of dots or dashes. Also, when a Host Name has 1 or more alpha characters in front of an octet, a dash needs to be inserted between the alpha character and the 1st digit of the octet.

This was my last attempt that only gets an IP when the delimiters are dots.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String returnValue = string.Empty;
// String _hostName -> passed  in as a method parameter.
sb.Append("\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.");
sb.Append("(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]");
sb.Append("[0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|[1-9]?[0-9])\\b");
if (Regex.IsMatch(_hostname, sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   returnValue = Regex.Match(_hostname, sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;
```

The above RegEx produces these results on a DNS Host Name

```
// Example 1: Input string "a121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: ""
// Example 2: Input string "121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: ""
// Example 3: Input string "a121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: ""
// Example 4: Input string "121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121.213.219.33"
// Example 5: Input string "abc-121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: ""
// Example 6: Input string "abc.121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121.213.219.33"
```

For only the IP address, this is what I’m trying to get by using RegEx:

```
// Example 1: Input string "121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121.213.219.33"
// Example 3: Input string "121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121.213.219.33"
// Example 4: Input string "abc-121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121.213.219.33"
```

Host Names are more problematic. This next example pulls the entire Host Name from a line of text but again fails if an octet has a leading alpha character and it doesn’t format the Host Name component with dash delimiters.

```
sb.Append("^(?!.{256})(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\\.|[a-z0-9]\\.)+(?:[a-z]{2}");
sb.Append("|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|BIZ|CAT|COM|COOP|EDU|GOV|INFO|INT|JOBS|MIL|MOBI|MUSEUM|NAME|NET|ORG|POST|PRO|TEL|TRAVEL|XXX)$");

if (Regex.IsMatch(_hostname, sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
   returnValue = Regex.Match(_hostname, sb.ToString(), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Value;


// Matches a DNS Host Name
// Example 1: Input string "a121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "a121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 2: Input string "121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 3: Input string "a121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "a121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 4: Input string "121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: “121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com”
// Example 5: Input string "abc-121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "abc-121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 6: Input string "abc.121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "abc.121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com"
```

For Host Names, what I’m trying to get returned looks like this, notice the consistent use of delimiters in the Host Name component:

```
// Example 1: Input string "a121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "a-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 2: Input string "121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 3: Input string "a121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "a-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 4: Input string "121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: “121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com”
// Example 5: Input string "abc-121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"
// Example 6: Input string "abc.121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com" -> Returns: "abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"
```

Also notice that when a Host Name such as "abc121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com" is presented, the Regex, in addition to matching an octet that has leading characters, needs to insert a dash between those characters and the 1st digit in the IP octet.

The final format for DB storage should look like this:

```
"abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com" or
"121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com" but not like
"abc121-213-219-33-.hostName.some.domain.com" and not like
"abc-121.213.219.33.hostName.some.domain.com"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is "only" `abc121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com` to map to `abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com` then don't use a regexp at all (also don't badly obfuscate, `domain.com` exists, use `example.com` instead). You just need to first split on `.` then split the first label on `-` and non digits and then reassemble everything. As for the rest, do not hardcode TLDs, lists are bound to change... and your regexp in general is wrong as TLDs can be IDNs too, so of the form `xn--` which your regexp refuses (and other problems)

Comment: I agree with Patrick, you may want to consider writing a parser that doesn't use regex.

Comment: Thanks, guys, figured there was a 50/50 chance this might be the response. One more question for those with more experience. While one all-encompassing RegEx is asking too much, might there still be an advantage by breaking all the steps down into multiple smaller steps? For example, creating a RegEx library of small atomic-like functions that can be chained together as needed to complete a larger task? Wouldn't there be some advantage over C# methods, with regards to ease of understanding and maintaining code?

Comment: Re *"One more question ..."*. This should probably be asked as a new question. You might give a link to this question to give context. But be careful how you phrase the new question or it might be closed a "opinion based".

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your question suffers from *analysis paralysis* by over-providing things like, .Net 3, the original source code, and all the failures....

What one should ask for, is a pattern, and show before/after possibilities; and there was only one clear example of a *before* and *after*. :-/

Because of that, I will only address the one item which was clearly presented. Then one can convert what I write into .Net 3.

---

> "abc121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com", such strings need to be formatted like this, "abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com"

This pattern should handle the ips addys and the domain issue.

```
var pattern = @"
^                          # Beginning of the line
 (?<IPLetters>[a-zA-Z]+)?  # If letters, then match
(
   (?<Octet>\d+)           # IP numbers and a
    \W                     # . or a - (not a word)
 ){4}                      # 4 of them
(?<Host>.+)                # The rest is the host.
";

// Result:   abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com
var input = "abc121-213-219-33.hostName.some.domain.com";

var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern,
                        RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace); // allows pattern commenting


var IPLetters = match.Groups["IPLetters"].Success 
              ? match.Groups["IPLetters"].Value.ToString() 
              : string.Empty;

var IPAddress = string.Join('-', 
                             match.Groups["Octet"].Captures
                                                  .OfType<Capture>()
                                                  .Select(cp => cp.Value)
                                                  .ToList());

var host = match.Groups["Host"].Value.ToString();

var hasIPLetters = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPLetters);

Console.WriteLine($"{IPLetters}{(hasIPLetters ? "-" : string.Empty)}{IPAddress}-{host}");
```

The result of the above code:

`abc-121-213-219-33-hostName.some.domain.com`

---

##### What to fix if porting back to V3.

- Var will need to be removed.
- String interpolation changed to `string.Format`.
- Linq was introduced in .Net 3.5

##### What stays the same

- String literal
- Anyting regex is still the same, including options.